# Convex linear combination of interior sets

Tags: real-analysis

Given a generic set $C$ and given its interior $C^O$, how do you prove that $C^O \subseteq [\alpha C^O + (1-\alpha) C^O]$ for $\forall \alpha \in [0 , 1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $C \subseteq X$ for some real topological vector space. Let $x \in C^\circ$. As $C^\circ$ is open, there is some neighbourhood $U$ of zero, such that $x+ U \subseteq C^\circ$. We may suppose that $U = -U$ and $[-1,1]\cdot U \subseteq U$. Let $u \in U - \{0\}$, then $v := (1-\alpha)u \in U$ and $w := -\alpha u \in U$. Note that $0 = (1-\alpha)w + \alpha v$, hence 
$$ x = (1-\alpha)(x+w) + \alpha(x+v) \in (1-\alpha)(x+U) + \alpha(x+U) \subseteq (1-\alpha)C^\circ + \alpha C^\circ $$

Comment: What does the notation $-U$ and $[-1,1]\cdot U$ mean in this context?

Comment: $-U = \{-u \mid u \in U\}$, $[-1,1] \cdot U = \{\lambda u \mid \lambda \in [-1,1], u \in U\}$.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Just one clarification. Why is it that $0 = (1-\alpha)w + \alpha v$?

Comment: Just pluging in the definitions of $v$ and $w$ we have $$ (1-\alpha)w + \alpha v = (1-\alpha)(-\alpha u) + \alpha(1-\alpha)u = 0$$